# Убрать правую часть строки до определенного символа, без изменений левой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Дана мне вот такая строка.

```
Receive Stop espionage activities                                   := 0
Receive Stop sabotage activities                                    := 0
Receive Stop attacks in system                                      := 0
Receive Surrender                                                   := 10
```

Мне нужно чтобы вся правая часть после символа ":= " была удалена, оставив при этом левую. Я сделал такую формулу [^.*:=]+$ насколько хорошо она справиться с задачей?

Примечание: 2 день голову ломаю. Знаю только как убрать правую, с потерей левой.(.*:=)

Comment: То есть нужно убрать числовые значения?

Comment: Да, если будут символы, то их тоже.

Comment: Используйте макрос.

Comment: – user7860670
Его ещё сделать надо, хотя бы основе регулярки.

Comment: Я имел ввиду клавиатурный макрос. А если все данные выровнены, как в примере, то вообще просто вертикальный блок выделите у удалите.

Comment: Я не знаю как с этим работать и не знаю как в n++ выделить текст как блок. Мне чтобы долго не искать, если у тебя есть об этом(макросах клавиатурных) справочник для чайников, что-то такое?

Comment: Блоками можно выделять как обычно мышью, но удерживая Alt (Это кстати работает в Visual Studio и много где еще). Макросы записываются кнопками на тулбаре (Start Recording и т.д.) Все это есть [в справке к программе](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/macros/).

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь следующей регуляркой: `\:=.*` (https://regexr.com/6dvrl). Она выберет только текст, расположенный после `:=`, и сотрёт его вместе с `:=`. Не забудьте также убрать галочку с `и новые строки`., чтобы формат остался.

UPD: вижу, кто-то заминусовал сообщение, но не понимаю почему. Если дело касается удаления и `:=`, то могу сказать, что 1) в вопросе не было сказано, *оставлять или нет эту последовательность*, и 2) `.*:=` — вариант из примечания — также удаляет эту последовательность.

Comment: Я не знаю как пользоваться сайтом.

Comment: @vadim990 в графе "Expression" находится регулярное выражение; ниже имеется графа "Текст", куда Вы можете вставить свой текст. Если выражение работает, то оно должно выделить часть текста с `:=` и символами после него (но не переход на новую строку).

Comment: Минусовщиков хватает. Но... _"в вопросе не было сказано..."_ Так вот же: _"Мне нужно чтобы вся правая часть после символа ":= " была удалена"_

Comment: @UModeL там говорилось лишь о том, чтобы удалить все символы _после_ этой последовательности, но про то, оставлять ли `:=` или нет, он ничего не сказал. В правой же части после символа этого же символа быть не может, ибо он является разделителем, верно?

Comment: 4500zenja
 Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

- Найти:

  ```
  ^([\w ]+:=).*$
  ```
- Заменить на:

  ```
  $1
  ```
- Учитывать регистр - *убрать флажок*
- Зациклить поиск - *поставить флажок*
- и новые строки - *убрать флажок*
- <kbd>Заменить все</kbd>

Comment: Обоснуйте минус, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что твоя формула, что моя. Она не убирает текст после ":=", например тут Response Friend Declare War 2                                     := What would lead you to such folly, [%TargetEmperorTitle]

Comment: Я минусы не ставлю никому. Я не знаю откуда они.

Comment: @vadim990: _"Она не убирает текст после..."_ У меня всё заменяет.

Comment: Спасибо, я ошибся!!! А где я могу узнать о ВСЕХ символах поддерживаемых n++ и то, как они работают? Я до сих пор не нашёл в сети и справочнике, как работает знак :.

Comment: @vadim990: [Notepad++. Диалог "Найти и заменить"](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/)

Comment: И всё же отказывается удалять, например:                                                                                                 Send Refuse Treaty 8        := We see no advantage to joining an alliance with you.
Я над этим голову попробую поломать сам. Спасибо.

Comment: @vadim990: Проверил. Всё нормально заменяет.

Comment: А флажок "Учитывать регистр" у тебя отмечена? У меня да. Наверное не в этом дело?

Comment: @vadim990: Нет, этот флажок у меня снят.